# Can't get Promise in response from background script in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to communicate asynchronously between content and background script in Firefox Extension. Background script receives message from content.
MDN indicates, that browser.runtime.sendMessage returns Promise, so it is possible use .than to attach callbacks to it. However, when trying to call it, I get error message: 
TypeError: sending.than is not a function.

What's wrong?

I'm using Linux, Firefox v 60.0.1, loading extension as temporary via about:debugging page.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "messagetest",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Testing content to background message sending",

  "icons": {
    "32": "icons/bird.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

content.js:

```
function handleResponse(msg)
{
    console.log("Response HANDLED:  " + msg);
}

function handleError(e)
{
    console.log("ERROR HANDLED");
}

var sending = browser.runtime.sendMessage({request: "messagetest"});
sending.than(handleResponse, handleError);
```

background.js:

```
function onContentMessage(msg, sender, handleResponse)
{
console.log("MESSAGE RECEIVED");
handleResponse("RESPOND FROM BACKGROUND:");
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onContentMessage);
```

Comment: Have you tried sending.then instead?

Comment: You are right, problem is in 'sending.than', and it has nothing to do with messages. When using 'sending.then( result => {...}' instead, it works. I think I should read a bit more about javascript syntactics.